# Einstein summation pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, rule

I have an expression of the form

expr = $(A\cdot B)\;(C\cdot D)\;(F\cdot G)$

where $A, B,C, D, F, G$ are all vectors. I would like to use Einstein summation convention for each dot product and then simplify the expression. I attempt by writing a rule

```
rule = Dot[x_,y_]-> Times[Superscript[x,i],Superscript[y,i]]
```

But when I replace this rule in the expr all the dot products transform with similar indices. How can I achieve the following?

$(A^iB^i)\;(C^jD^j)\;(F^\ell G^\ell)$

Answer (score 1):

Define a set of indices

```
 ijk=Symbol/@CharacterRange["i","q"]
 SetAtributes[ijk,{Protected}]
```

and an indexpointer

```
ipt;
```

Now you can replace series of different dot products

```
 rule = {ipt = 1; 
    (a_Symbol . b_Symbol) :> 
    (Subscript[a, ijk[[#]]]*Subscript[b, ijk[[#]]] &)[ipt++]}
```

For more than a small number of products there is no way to avoid subscripted indices.

Feynman, confronted with possibly infinite many indices simply used the integers discarding the superflous $i$ in

$$    a\cdot b * c\cdot d = a_1 b_1 c_2 d_2 $$

instead of

$$a_{i_1} b_{i_1}   c_{i_2} d{i_2} \dots $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your suggestion works. However for long expressions it seems that the indices from {i to q } will be run out and produce an error. How to modify it to include $(1⋅1)(1⋅1)(1⋅1) + (2⋅2)(2⋅2)(2⋅2)$ ? Or how to modify you suggestion such that after each Plus to start with again the same index "i"?

Comment: Generally you have to use different indices in all kinds of products. over sums the set may be identical for each .  Another approach is using Unique

(a_Symbol . b_Symbol) :> 
    (Subscript[a, #]*Subscript[b, #] &)[Unique[j]]}

Answer (score 1):

By introducing a counter "c" into the rule you can achieve different indices. (Note you did not use "Dot" in your expression" but character 22C5D):

```
expr = (A . B) (C . D) (F . G)
c = 0;
rule := Dot[x_, y_] :> Times[Superscript[x, Symbol["i" <> ToString[++c]]], Superscript[y, Symbol["i" <> ToString[c]]]]
expr /. rule
```

[image]

Comment: solution is at [Scalar product of vectors using dummy indices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291693/scalar-product-of-vectors-using-dummy-indices/292066#292066)