# Scalar product of vectors using dummy indices

Tags: vector, dot, notation

How can I rewrite the following expression

$expr1= (A\cdot B)(C\cdot D)(E\cdot F) + (A^\prime\cdot B^\prime)(C^\prime\cdot D^\prime)(E^\prime\cdot F^\prime) +\cdots $

in terms of the components as

$expr2= A_iB_i\;C_jD_j\;E_\ell F_\ell + A^\prime_iB^\prime_i\;C^\prime_jD^\prime_j\;E^\prime_\ell F^\prime_\ell +\cdots $

where $A,A^\prime\cdots F, F^\prime$ are 3D vectors. I start with the following rule

```
rule = {incr = 1; var = CharacterRange["i", "q"];
Dot[a_, b_] :> (Subscript[a, var[[#]]]*Subscript[b, var[[#]]] &)[
 incr++]}
```

but at some point I ran out of indices. How to modify the rule such that it starts with the index $i$ in each some as in $expr2$?

Comment: Large space algebraists use subscripted subscripts: rule = {incr = 1;
Dot[a_, b_] :> (Subscript[a, Subscript[i,#] ] * Subscript[b, Subscript[i,#] ]&)[
 incr++]}

Comment: You can use a rule like e.g.:  `a1 . b1 c1 . d1 e1 . f1 + a2 . b2 c2 . d2  e2 . f2 /. 
 HoldPattern[a_ . b_  c_ . d_  e_ . f_ ] :> ( 
   Subscript[a, i] Subscript[b, i]  Subscript[c, j] Subscript[d, j]
      Subscript[e, k] Subscript[f, k]) `  but take care to put a space after each "_". Otherwise you will get some unwanted interpretations.

Answer (score 1):

If we take the requirements literally, with the number of vector groups being 4:

```
(# /: Format[#[i_Integer][j_]] := 
     Subsuperscript[ToUpperCase[SymbolName[#]], j, 
      StringJoin[Table["\[Prime]", i - 1]]]) & /@ {a, b, c, d, e, f};
toComponents[v_] := Array[v, 3];

Sum[(a[j] . b[j]) (c[j] . d[j]) (e[j] . f[j]) /. 
    v : a | b | c | d | e | f :> (toComponents[v[#]] &), {j, 4}] // 
  Expand // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will just give what I want:

```
For[
term = 1; finalexpr = 0, 
term <= Length@(expr1/.Plus -> List),       
incr = 1,
rule = # /. Dot[a_, b_] :>   (Superscript[a, Subscript[i, #]]*
      Superscript[b, Subscript[i, #]] &)[incr++] &;
dottodummy = rule /@(expr1/.Plus -> List)[[term]];
finalexpr += dottodummy;
term++;
];

finalexpr
```

Now to test it let's define the input

$(\text{A1}.\text{B1}) (\text{C1}.\text{D1}) (\text{E1}.\text{F1})+(\text{A2}.\text{B2}) (\text{C2}.\text{D2} )(\text{E2}.\text{F2})+(\text{A3}.\text{B3}) (\text{C3}.\text{D3}) (\text{E3}.\text{F3})$

as

```
expr1 = Dot[A1, B1] Dot[C1, D1] Dot[E1, F1] + Dot[A2, B2] Dot[C2, D2] Dot[E2, F2] + Dot[A3, B3] Dot[C3, D3] Dot[E3, F3]
```

then running the code gives

```
finalexpr    
Superscript[A1,Subscript[i, 1]] Superscript[B1,Subscript[i, 1]] Superscript[C1,Subscript[i, 2]] Superscript[D1,Subscript[i, 2]] Superscript[E1,Subscript[i, 3]] Superscript[F1,Subscript[i, 3]] + 
Superscript[A2,Subscript[i, 1]] Superscript[B2,Subscript[i, 1]] Superscript[C2,Subscript[i, 2]] Superscript[D2,Subscript[i, 2]] Superscript[E2,Subscript[i, 3]] Superscript[F2,Subscript[i, 3]] + 
Superscript[A3,Subscript[i, 1]] Superscript[B3,Subscript[i, 1]] Superscript[C3,Subscript[i, 2]] Superscript[D3,Subscript[i, 2]] Superscript[E3,Subscript[i, 3]] Superscript[F3,Subscript[i, 3]]
```

in plain text as

$\text{A1}^{i_1} \text{B1}^{i_1} \text{C1}^{i_2} \text{D1}^{i_2} \text{E1}^{i_3} \text{F1}^{i_3}+\text{A2}^{i_1} \text{B2}^{i_1} \text{C2}^{i_2} \text{D2}^{i_2} \text{E2}^{i_3} \text{F2}^{i_3}+\text{A3}^{i_1} \text{B3}^{i_1} \text{C3}^{i_2} \text{D3}^{i_2} \text{E3}^{i_3} \text{F3}^{i_3}$

Comment: You could improve your answer by applying your solution to the expression given in the question..

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on what your actually want to do: to compute or just to rewrite expression in nice form. Below I define few solution using replacement rules from good to very bad style.

1. That is good for programming

   dotRules = {Dot[a_, b_] :> With[{k = Unique[i]}, a[k] b[k]]};

   expr1 /. dotRules

(*out1 *)

```
A1[i$22465] B1[i$22465] C1[i$22466] D1[i$22466] E1[i$22467] F1[
       i$22467] + 
     A2[i$22468] B2[i$22468] C2[i$22469] D2[i$22469] E2[i$22470] F2[
       i$22470]
```

2. That is not very bad, however intended not for further computation but mostly for representation

   ```
    dotRulesBadStyle = {Dot[a_, b_] :> 
       With[{k = Unique[i]}, Superscript[a, k] Superscript[b, k]]};
    expr1 /. dotRulesBadStyle
   ```

   (*out2 *)

   ```
    Superscript[A1,i$22473] Superscript[B1,i$22473] Superscript[
      C1,i$22474] Superscript[D1,i$22474] Superscript[
      E1,i$22475] Superscript[F1,i$22475] + 
     Superscript[A2,i$22476] Superscript[B2,i$22476] Superscript[
      C2,i$22477] Superscript[D2,i$22477] Superscript[
      E2,i$22478] Superscript[F2,i$22478]
   ```
3. that is very bad, since it uses global counter and superscripts

   ```
     globalCounter = 0;
        dotRulesVeryBadStyle = {Dot[a_, b_] :> 
           With[{k = Unique[i], 
             localIndex = "i" <> ToString[globalCounter++]}, 
            Superscript[a, localIndex] Superscript[b, localIndex]]}
   ```

   expr1 /. dotRulesVeryBadStyle

(*out3 *)

```
Superscript[A1,"i0"] Superscript[B1,"i0"] Superscript[
  C1,"i1"] Superscript[D1,"i1"] Superscript[E1,"i2"] Superscript[
  F1,"i2"] + 
 Superscript[A2,"i3"] Superscript[B2,"i3"] Superscript[
  C2,"i4"] Superscript[D2,"i4"] Superscript[E2,"i5"] Superscript[
  F2,"i5"]
```